# CSS transform-origin center won't evenly expand width or height as expected

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to understand how to use transform-origin to create an even 'growth' with width or height. Why won't it work to expand from the center where I've specified transform origin?

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: height 2s;

   -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
           transform-origin: center center;
}

div:hover {
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: -webkit-transform-origin works only on transform property, not the height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

transform-origin works only with transformed things, not `height` or others.

> The transform-origin property is used in conjunction with CSS
>   transforms, letting you change the point of origin of a transform.

```
.box {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

[Source](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform-origin/)

if you want to do this you can use in conjunction with `margin-top` to have the result that you want:

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: all 2s;
}

div:hover {
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: -100px; // (300px - 100px) / 2
}
```

**[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dwnu7vhb/)**